# Funcion #define

Tags: c, funciones, variables-globales

En un código en el que se usa `#define` REGLA 90, antes de la funcion `main()`,
¿Hay alguna forma de que el valor de la variable, en este ejemplo el 90, se pida cuando se ejecuta el programa, en lugar de tener que introducirlo en el código, cada vez que se quiera cambiar?

Gracias.

Answer (score 5):

`#define` no se usa para declarar variables sino macros o constantes a procesar por el precompilador y no puede, por tanto, ver sus valores modificados en tiempo de ejecución. Para hacer lo que pides tienes que usar variables:

```
int main()
{
  int variable;                    // <<--- Variable
  printf("Introduce un numero: ");
  scanf("%d",&variable);           // <<--- El usuario modifica su valor
}
```

Comment: ¿Y una constante declarada con #define se podría, entonces, cambiar a variable, e introducirla dentro de main(), sin que afectara al funcionamiento del programa?

Comment: @Vacendak lo que declaras con `#define` el precompilador lo reemplaza por su valor... luego en el código fuente no encuentras una variable sino un valor escrito a pelo... y eso no puedes modificarlo de ninguna forma

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices. Es que no sabía que funcionaba como una constante. Probaré a quitar el #define y meterlo como una variable dentro del programa, para poder pedir el valor al ejecutar el programa. Al fin de cuentas lo que importa es usar el valor en los puntos donde interviene, ¿no? Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @Vacendak depende de lo que estés haciendo... es arriesgado darte una respueta final sin conocer el código

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es que al llamar al programa se ejecute con determinado valor igual lo que te conviene es pasar ese valor al momento de invocar el programa

por ejemplo:
Programa 10

Luego podrás capturar ese valor dentro de tu código

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

El primer argumento de la función argc indica el número total de parámetros.
El segundo argumento argv, permite acceder a los valores de los parámetros pasados al programa.
(siempre el primer parámetro, es decir argv[0] contiene el nombre del programa)

por tanto argv[1] contendrá el valor 10

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no quiero hacerlo por línea de comandos, sino ejecutando el programa desde windows.

Comment: desde windows tambien se le pueden pasar valores ;) solo basta con modificar el acceso directo...

Answer (score 2):

Creo que no entendes bien el concepto de lo que es un `#define`, la directiva de precompilacion `#define` se usa para crear macros, en este caso reemplaza una palabra en tu codigo por otra porcion de codigo, supongamos que tu programa se ve asi:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define VALOR 90

int main(){
    printf("%d\n",VALOR);
    return 0;
}
```

En el paso del precompilador, tu funcion main pasara a verse de esta forma:

```
int main(){
    printf("%d\n",90);
    return 0;
}
```

Entonces VALOR no es una variable, ni una constante, sino que es un numero harcodeado en tu programa, no hay manera de cambiarlo sin recompilar ya que ese 90 pasa a ser parte del codigo de tu programa.
Lo que hay que hacer como bien decis, es **declarar una variable** (en este caso en scope global, ya que el define afecta al mismo scope y esta marcado en las tags de la pregunta)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int valor;

int main(){
    printf("Por favor introduzca un valor: ");
    scanf("%d",&valor);
    printf("%d\n",valor);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adjunto un código de ejemplo, para que lo revisen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define REGLA 10

int main(int argc, char **argv){
        if (argc<2){
                printf("Uso:\nredefine.exe <numero>\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        int numero=0;
        numero=atoi(argv[1]);

        printf("Valor REGLA  :%d\n",REGLA);
        printf("Valor numero :%d\n",numero);

        #ifdef REGLA
                #undef REGLA
                #define REGLA numero
        #endif

        printf("Valor REGLA Redef :%d\n",REGLA);
}
```

Comment: Esto debería ser una edición de tu otra respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

se puede usar `#undef` y luego nuevamente `#def`, luego del main

```
#ifdef REGLA
   #undef  REGLA
   #define REGLA   <variable o nuevo valor>
#endif
```

Comment: Para nada, no funcionará en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: veo que no lo han probado